# How to fallback to a default value when ansible lookup fails?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I was a little bit surprised to discover that his piece of code fails with an IOError exception instead of defaulting to omitting the value.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ansible-playbook -i localhost,
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="{{ lookup('ini', 'foo section=DEFAULT file=missing-file.conf') | default(omit) }}"
```

How can I load a value without raising an exception?

Please note that the lookup module supports a default value parameter but this one is useless to me because it works only when it can open the file.

I need a default value that works even when the it fails to open the file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know Jinja2 unfortunately doesn't support any try/catch mechanism.

So you either patch ini lookup plugin / file issue to Ansible team, or use this ugly workaround:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="{{ lookup('first_found', dict(files=['test-ini.conf'], skip=true)) | ternary(lookup('ini', 'foo section=DEFAULT file=test-ini.conf'), omit) }}"
```

In this example `first_found` lookup return file name if file exists or empty list otherwise. If file exists, `ternary` filter calls `ini` lookup, otherwise `omit` placeholder is returned.

Comment: Ugly would be an understatement, maybe hideous is more appropriate! ;) On the bright side it seems to be working. Still, i will avoid it because it make code very hard to read or review for others. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In case people like me stumble upon this question in 2022,
Ansible now supports rescue blocks, which is similar to try-catch-finally in programming languages.

Examples can be found in the official documentation [Error handling with blocks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html#handling-errors-with-blocks).

Answer (score 1):

You can use block/rescue as follows:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - block:
        - debug: msg="{{ lookup('ini', 'foo section=DEFAULT file=missing-file.conf') }}"
      rescue:
        - debug: msg="omit"
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the error when the path doesn't exist, use a condition to check for the path before attempting the lookup:

```
---

- hosts: localhost
  tasks:

    - debug: msg="{{ lookup('ini', 'foo section=DEFAULT file=missing-file.conf') }}"
      when: missing-file.conf | exists
```

You can use this with `set_fact` as well, then omit the undefined var when using it if required:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        foo: "{{ lookup('ini', 'foo section=DEFAULT file=missing-file.conf') }}"
      when: missing-file.conf | exists

    - debug:
        var: foo  # undefined
        msg: "{{ foo | default(omit) }}"  # omitted
```

Note that lookups and [Jinja2 tests](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-paths) run on the *controller*. If you need to check the path on the host, use the `stat` and either `slurp` or `fetch` modules:

```
- stat:
    file: missing-remote-file-with-text-i-want
  register: file

- slurp:
    src: missing-remote-file-with-text-i-want
  register: slurp
  when: file.stat.exists

- set_fact:
    foo: "{{ slurp.content | b64decode }}"
  when: file.stat.exists

- fetch:
    src: missing-file.conf
    dest: /tmp/fetched
    fail_on_missing: False

- set_fact:
    bar: "{{ lookup('ini', 'foo section=DEFAULT file=/tmp/fetched/' + inventory_hostname + '/missing-file.conf') }}"
  when: ('/tmp/fetched/' + inventory_hostname + '/missing-file.conf') | exists
```

Second note, in Ansible `v2.5` the grammar for using the path tests was changed, the format is now:

```
- set_fact:
    foo: "{{ lookup('ini', 'foo section=DEFAULT file=missing-file.conf') }}"
  when: '"missing-file.conf" is exists'
```

Comment: The syntax shown here -- `when: missing-file.conf is exists` -- is invalid. For that to work, you would need to quote the filename: `when: '"missisng-file.conf" is exists'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert your input file with a `from_yaml` filter before using the default filter

```
- name: "load a yaml file or a default value"
  set_fact:
    myvar: "{{ lookup('file', 'myfile.yml', errors='ignore') | from_yaml | default(mydefaultObject, true) }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

From the info above is was able to add ",errors='ignore'" to the lookup and then follow it with a `default` value.

e.g. in a task with_items

```
ansible.posix.authorized_key:
  key: "{{ lookup('file', auth_key | default('./files/ssh-key-{{ item }}.pub'), errors='ignore') | default('NO-key-file-for {{ item }} }}')}}"
```