# Performing an Ansible lookup using first_found and skip

Tags: ansible

I'd like to perform a lookup in Ansible using `first_found` as well as its `skip` option. I've created the following play to do so:

```
- name: Include group playbooks
  include: "{{lookup('first_found', dict=(files=[item + '.yml', 'empty.yml'], skip=true))}}"
  with_items: "{{group_names}}"
```

I'm receiving this error, however:

```
ERROR! Unexpected Exception: '_raw_params'
```

How can I pass `skip` option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I doubt your `dict=` parameters passing. See my [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43225699/2795592) answer for correct call.

And about your error: `first_found` lookup with `skip` option returns empty list if nothing is found – but `include` statement expects filename as free-form parameter.

You can workaround it like this:

```
- name: Include group playbooks
  include: "{{ filename }}"
  when: filename is string
  vars:
    filename: "{{ lookup('first_found', dict(files=[item + '.yml', 'empty.yml'], skip=true)) }}"
  with_items: "{{group_names}}"
```

Comment: Ahhhhh... I see!  I misunderstood where the error was actually occurring. Using your code from above, it now works. Thank you for the assist!